# Extract UTC date from timezone aware string

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a string and I need to convert it first to  utc and then extract the date from it.

```
times = '2021-04-15T21:53:00:000-06'
```

I am first doing:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(times, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

It's giving me exception as:

> ValueError: time data '2021-04-15T21:53:00-06' does not match format
> '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'

I want to replace the timezone to utc replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
and extract only yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the format is consistent in your data (length of the strings is constant), you can do a bit of string slicing to separate date/time and UTC offset. Parse the first to `datetime` and add the latter as a `timezone` constructed from a `timedelta`. Then convert to UTC.

Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

s = '2021-04-15T21:53:00:000-06'

# first part to datetime
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(s[:-3])

# set time zone
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=int(s[-3:]))))

# to UTC
dt_utc = dt.astimezone(timezone.utc)

print(dt_utc.date())
# 2021-04-16
```

Note that this will fail if the format *is not consistent*, e.g. if some strings have `+0530` while others only have e.g. `-06`.

In that case, another option is to use `strptime`, but that requires modifying the input as well. `%z` expects `±HH:MM` or `±HHMM`, so you can add the minutes like

```
if len(s) == 26: # minutes missing
    s += '00'

dt = datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%f%z")
```

and then convert to UTC as described above.